# How to read unique elements from array per thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scalability

I have an object based on array, which implements the following interface:

```
public interface PairSupplier<Q, E> {
     public int size();

     public Pair<Q, E> get(int index);
}
```

I would like to create a specific iterator over it:

```
public boolean hasNext(){
     return true;
}

public Pair<Q, E> next(){
     //some magic
}
```

In method **next** I would like to return some element from **PairSupplier**.

This element should be unique for thread, other threads should not have this element.

Since PairSupplier has a final size, this situation is not always possible, but I would like to approach it.

The **order** of elements doesn't matter, thread can take same element at a **different** time.

**Example**:   `2 Threads`, `5 elements` - **`{1,2,3,4,5}`**

```
Thread 1  | Thread 2
   1           2
   3           4
   5           1
   3           2
   4           5
```

**My solution**:

I create AtomicInteger index, which I increment on every **next** call.

```
PairSupplier pairs;
AtomicInteger index;

public boolean hasNext(){
     return true;
}

public Pair<Q, E> next(){
     int position = index.incrementAndGet() % pairs.size;
     if (position < 0) {
          position *= -1;
          position = pairs.size - position;
     }
     return pairs.get(position);
}
```

**pairs** and **index** are shared among all threads.

I found this solution not scalable (because all threads go for increment), maybe someone have better ideas?

This iterator will be used by **50-1000 threads**.

Comment: Is that complete code ?

Comment: this [example(s)](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#ai) may help.

Comment: @SachinThapa no, I only would like to show the problem and a part of possible solution

Comment: What about using JMS with non-durable messages?

Comment: You said: _This element should be unique for thread, other threads should not have this element._ But in your example thread 2 accesses `1` that has already been accessed by thread 1? Or do i miss something? Ahh my bad, just read the *different* time thing. So how do you know that the thread has finished processing the element?

Comment: @ortang The processing of all elements has almost the same time in all threads.

Comment: @MaryRyllo ok, but that does **NOT** indicate if/when the processing thread is executed/scheduled/finished. You have to build some mechanism that notifies the `PairSupplier` when the processing of an element is done.

Comment: @ortang this situation is not critical. I assume it, but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @MaryRyllo, ok. As you mentioned: *This element should be unique for thread*, so it does not have to be unique, then @OldCurmudgeon answer should fit your problem well. If you however discover that you must not share the `Pair` between multiple threads concurrently, you could use a token based approach: init a (concurrent) FIFO queue with `Integer`s representing the indices of the array. Take/Insert a queue element(array index) on `next()`/worker finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question details are ambiguous - your example suggests that two threads **can** be handed the same `Pair` but you say otherwise in the description.

As the more difficult to achieve, I will offer an `Iterable<Pair<Q,E>>` that will deliver `Pair`s one per thread until the supplier cycles - then it will repeat.

```
public interface Supplier<T> {
  public int size();

  public T get(int index);

}

public interface PairSupplier<Q, E> extends Supplier<Pair<Q, E>> {
}

public class IterableSupplier<T> implements Iterable<T> {
  // The common supplier to use across all threads.
  final Supplier<T> supplier;
  // The atomic counter.
  final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();

  public IterableSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    /**
     * You may create a NEW iterator for each thread while they all share supplier
     * and Will therefore distribute each Pair between different threads.
     *
     * You may also share the same iterator across multiple threads.
     *
     * No two threads will get the same pair twice unless the sequence cycles.
     */
    return new ThreadSafeIterator();
  }

  private class ThreadSafeIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      /**
       * Always true.
       */
      return true;
    }

    private int pickNext() {
      // Just grab one atomically.
      int pick = i.incrementAndGet();
      // Reset to zero if it has exceeded - but no spin, let "just someone" manage it.
      int actual = pick % supplier.size();
      if (pick != actual) {
        // So long as someone has a success before we overflow int we're good.
        i.compareAndSet(pick, actual);
      }
      return actual;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      return supplier.get(pickNext());
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove not supported.");
    }

  }

}
```

NB: I have adjusted the code a little to accommodate both scenarios. You can take an `Iterator` per thread or share a single `Iterator` across threads.

Comment: Your solution looks good, I prefer idea with atomic index too, but I try to find something without synchronization. Another users advice to use buckets, but it is not my case(read previous answers). May be random function can solve my problem? But I don't know how to use random in multi threading environment.

Comment: @MaryRyllo - There is no synchronization here - you are unlikely to find anything better but by all means research other options. Note that I have adjusted the code to accomodate either scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You have a piece of information ("has anyone taken this `Pair` already?") that must be shared between all threads.  So for the general case, you're stuck.  However, if you have an idea about this size of your array and the number of threads, you could use buckets to make it less painful.

Let's suppose we know that there will be 1,000,000 array elements and 1,000 threads.  Assign each thread a range (thread #1 gets elements 0-999, etc).  Now instead of 1,000 threads contending for one AtomicInteger, you can have no contention at all!

That works if you can be sure that all your threads will run at about the same pace. If you need to handle the case where sometimes thread #1 is busy doing other things while thread #2 is idle, you can modify your bucket pattern slightly: each bucket has an AtomicInteger.  Now threads will *generally* only contend with themselves, but if their bucket is empty, they can move on to the next bucket.

Comment: I thought about buckets, it is a good idea(+1 to exp), but I don't know about thread count. It can grow dynamically. And I would like to use pairs as more as possible and try to avoid usage of same pairs.

Comment: Some buckets is better than one (what you have now). If the number of threads grew way beyond your guess, you could lock the entire PairSupplier and re-bucket (but that will almost certainly be more expensive). You could have each `next()` return multiple elements depending on the thread count (that's *sort of* like dynamic buckets).

Comment: I like it - a resizeable bucket-list :)

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot My application simulate TPS load. To keep up exact tps count I add or remove some threads. So number of threads is changed very often =(

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some trouble understanding what the problem you are trying to solve is?

Does each thread process the whole collection?

Is the concern that no two threads can work on the same Pair at the same time?  But each thread needs to process each Pair in the collection?

Or do you want the collection processed once by using all of the threads?

Answer (score 0):

There is one key thing which is obscure in your example - what exactly is the meaning this?

> The order of elements doesn't matter, thread can take same element at a different time.

"different time" means what?  Within N milliseconds of each other?  Does it mean that absolutely two threads will never be touching the same Pair at the same time?  I will assume that.

If you want to decrease the probability that threads will block on each other contending for the same Pair, and there is a backing array of Pairs, try this:

- Partition your array into `numPairs / threadCount` sub-arrays (you don't have to actually create sub-arrays, just start at different offsets - but it's easier to think about as sub-array)
- Assign each thread to a different sub-array;  when a thread exhausts its sub-array, increment the index of its sub array

  - Say we have 6 Pairs and 2 threads - your assignments look like Thread-1:[0,1,2] Thread-2:[3,4,5]. When Thread-1 starts it will be looking at a different set of Pairs than thread 2, so it is unlikely that they will contend for the same pair
- If it is important that two threads *really* not touch a Pair at the same time, then wrap all of the code which touches a Pair object in `synchronized(pair)` (synchronize on the *instance*, not the type!) - there may occasionally be blocking, but you're never blocking all threads on a single thing, as with the `AtomicInteger` - threads can only block each other because they are really trying to touch the same object

Note this is **not guaranteed** never to block - for that, all threads would have to run at exactly the same speed, and processing every Pair object would have to take exactly the same amount of time, and the OS's thread scheduler would have to never steal time from one thread but not another.  You cannot assume any of those things.  What this gives you is a higher *probability* that you will get better concurrency, by dividing the areas to work in and making the smallest unit of state that is shared be the lock.

But this is the usual pattern for getting more concurrency on a data structure - partition the data between threads so that they rarely are touching the same lock at the same time.

Comment: "Does it mean that absolutely two threads will never be touching the same Pair at the same time" - yes, I would like to make it as possible as it could be =)

Answer (score 0):

The most easy that o see, is create Hash set or Map, and give a unique hash for every thread. After that just do simple get by this hash code.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard java semaphore usage problem. The following javadoc gives almost similar example as your problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

If you need more help, let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a lock and release process.

If a thread is asking for a pair object, the Pair object is removed from the supplier. Before the thread is asking for a new pair, the 'old' pair is added the the suplier again.

You can push from front and put at the end.